# Are questions based on conceptual (almost speculative) projects on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, specific-question

I have a question that is practical, but based on a speculative project.

I would like to know the effects on humans and cargo traveling on your standard, hypothetical [space elevator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator) of 100k km, because, I am having trouble visualizing it; you're not really in free-fall, but you have a constant velocity at some points, but then you're in space, but you're also traveling very fast, etc.

It relates well to Physics, but it's also speculative in the idea of the space elevator, so it relates well to Worldbuilding, but in the end, I felt it most strongly resembled a Space Exploration question.

**Where do space exploration questions based on hypothetical projects, go?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We currently have 20 questions tagged [space-elevator](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-elevator). You might find some of your questions already discussed and answered, so please check that before asking new ones to avoid duplication, but otherwise yes, questions about [conceptual](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conceptual), [feasibility](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feasibility), [physics](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics), even experience of and [health](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) implications on [humans](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humans) (I tried to write this sentence by using tag names, bear with me), and so on, of hypothetical space travel and exploration infrastructure is on-topic.